# Test Stack White attach to app which does not show up in the task manager

Tags: white-framework, teststack

I am working on an automated test and would like to perform actions on the windows event viewer. I have managed to open the event viewer through my test, but it does not attach to the app for me to make any actions like button presses/clicks as such.

The error showing is-

```
TestStack.White.WhiteException : Could not find process named: EventLog
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of ways to attach the program you need, on your case you are using the Process Name property, that's not recommended since there can be a process with the same name. You have to always try to use the Id of the Process, like below:

Start the process with the directory info and than use the Id to get hold:

```
var applicationPath = Path.Combine(applicationPath, "foo.exe");
Application application = Application.Launch(applicationPath);  //Launch, Attach and Launch and Attach are used here
Window window = application.GetWindow("bar", InitializeOption.NoCache); //You can get the window with that or use some other property that use the Id of the application variable above.
```